# style change to mailchimp form within squarespace

Tags: css, mailchimp, squarespace

I really appreciate the help.

If you are familiar with Squarespace, they have a mailchimp integration. I would like to make the submit button a little higher, but I don't know where to go to change the css within squarespace....nor what css to you use. I am familiar with css, but not within squarespace....and I'm still a beginner.

Either I would like the button a bit higher or to the side of the e-mail inbox. Whichever is easiest.

This is what it looks like now: http://screencast.com/t/cQISXcvl

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the class or id name of the element you want to change.
2. Go to "Style mode" in Squarespace.
3. At the bottom of the left design panel, click "Custom CSS".
4. Confirm that you know this might break your design. (Hint: It won't if you only target Mailchimp classes/id's)
5. Write your CSS and hit "save"
6. Refresh your page to see the changes.

**Example code for the input button in your case:**

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe{
float:left;
}
```

The above code can place your input button to the left. Or you can use

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe{
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

To reduse the top spacing. I hope that helps! If this doesn't solve it, please provide some code for me to work with.